# Columnar database queries in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm learning Amazon Redshift. Heard that it is very powerful storage on cloud and works very fast on data where aggregate operations are required because it stores data column-wise.

Am not able to find any example queries? Could someone share with me some examples of Aggregate queries running on Amazon Redshift? Is it different from normal relation database queries?

Answer (score 7):

You are correct -- Amazon Redshift is a **columnar database**. This means that data is stored on disk *per column*, making operations on a column very fast. For example, adding the Sales column for a particular value in the Country column only requires accessing two columns rather than all columns in a table.

Other benefits are that data in Redshift is **compressed** (which works well with the columnar concept, because each column uses its own compression method based on the data stored) and the fact that it is a **clustered database**, so compute and storage can be scaled by adding additional nodes.

Amazon Redshift presents itself as a **PostgreSQL database**, so you **just use industry-standard SQL** to query data. No changes to queries are required.

However, you can optimize Redshift by wisely choosing a **Distribution Key** for each table that determines how data is distributed amongst nodes, and carefully select the **Sort Key**, which determines how data is stored on each node. Put simply, data should be distributed by how you `JOIN` tables and should be sorted by what you use in `WHERE` statements.

As for **sample queries**... it totally depends upon your data! Queries look **exactly the same as normal SQL**.